# C header file usage and code reuse

Tags: c, header-files, code-reuse

Some C code for common tasks may be shared among projects and kept for future use. But how should I keep them? In *.c* or *.h*? I notice that C header files (.h) generally contains only function declarations, not definitions, and this seems to be the recommended practice.

1. Put **declarations** and **definitions** in `mycode.h`, so I can simplely `#include "myheader."` and leave all jobs to the compiler.
2. Put **declaration** in `mycode.h` and **definitions** in `mycode.c`. Probably conforming the convention? But I have to compile and link `mycode.c` each time.

What is the best practice? Any suggestions?

**EDIT**:

Everyone says #2 is the better practice. But how can I tell the compiler where the definition/implementation(.c/.o/.so?) reside in a header file? As I simply #include and use printf(...);?

Answer (score 2):

Make a library (.so or .dll - your poison) then link to it

The header file will then tell the compiler what is available to it

Comment: I would edit your answer, replacing '(.so or .dll - your poison)' by 'dynamically or statically linked". Would that be OK?

Comment: Could be.lib - but hey if you want static or dynamic (does dynamic sound more sexy?) then choose one or the other

Answer (score 1):

Option 2 is the best practice. Why is option 1 bad? If definitions exist in headers, those definitions have *global* scope. It strips away modularity of the software. Restricting the scope of variables is good practice as the software units are less coupled and therefore the software is easier to maintain.

Only the .c files that have changed need be compiled if a make system is used.

Comment: in option 1 only .h file need to be compiled so last one is not a logical argue....

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the number of files to be shared between your projects.

- if you got a **big** interconnected collection of files it is usually best to create a dynamic library or static library and link your application(s) statically or dynamically against that.
- In general - stick to #2

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is the second option, because it's not only simplicity but also about enhancement and maintaince

Answer (score 0):

Although not frequently used, I have seen projects that included lots of code in a .h. If you are positively sure that the code will only be used in one project only, I don't think that there is a major drawback in placing the code in the header, although it is quite unusual.

I would advise to place it in a .c though in order to be able to compile it as a separate module or shared library. This will ease the work of other developers and allow for a greater reusability.

Answer (score 0):

The header file is the window to the outer world, this is, **what** the code does (the interface). The **how it does** (details of implementation) is something that other modules and projects really don't care.

Suppose you own a grocery, and your client asks you for a dozen of apples. You:
-Check if there are apples in the display.
-If not, go to the back room to get some.
-If you ran out of apples, tell the client about it, and place an order to restore stock.

However, your client just wants his dozen of apples; does not care so much about the details of his order.

---

You may see cases in which the declaration and definition lay at the same .h file. When working with c++ templates this is mandatory as far as I am concerned. In the rest of the cases, it supposes extra build time, as those definitions will be compiled despite not having changed since the last build.

Comment: Thanks! But are there any way to tell the compiler where the definition/implementation(.c/.o/.so?) reside **in a header file**? As I simply `#include<stdio.h>` and use `printf(...);`?

Comment: stdio.h for example belongs to the C Standard Library. The files that comprise this library are "known in advance", and therefore you need not add them to your project. You just have to invoke them using their respective .h files.

Comment: If you were to use a third party library you'd probably see pairs of .h files and binary output files (.lib, .dll). By referencing your project to those output files, and using the .h files provided (which give you the means of accesing the functionalities) you can use those libraries. With the difference that you cannot access the implementation details (for the sake of encapsulation,building convenience, intellectual property or all of them...)

Answer (score 0):

Use Second Option ... Or Create the library whether it is dynamic (.so) or static (.a) it depends on you .. 
Yes, Dynamic Libraries Size is less compared to static Libraries.
So Second Option is best.